# Inside Out TDD and unit tests evolution

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I was developing application using Inside Out TDD and here is the sequence of steps I identified in this process:

1. Write test for basic functionality of class A
2. Create class A and implement needed functionality
3. Write test for additional functionality
4. Implement needed functionality in class A
5. Notice that class A violates SRP
6. Extract classes B and C whose services class A uses

Now, some of the questions I have on this "extracting crossroad" are:

***This assumes injecting dependencies for B and C in the class A. Should we use mocks for B and C or real instances?***

***If we should use real instances of B and C, do our unit tests now test more than one unit and do they become more than unit tests (integration or perhaps acceptance tests)?***

Also, If we should switch some of the original unit tests (targeting A) to test B and C for their functionality, I've noticed that it often becomes ***quite hard to write:***

1. ***Arrange part for tests testing B and C, and***
2. ***setting up the expectations for B and C mocks in unit tests for
   class A***

since the data communicated between A and B/C often become more granulated and difficult to setup.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very clear statement of the code costs of splitting out a class.  Also, the SRP is easy to over-apply (any procedure with more than one statement is self-evidently doing more than one thing, and 'responsibility' is a malleable term).

So I'll wait on that refactoring longer than I will on many others.  Still, it will come due eventually, so...

When the real class is hard to set up, or has real-world side-effects (and 'too slow' is in that bucket, for me), I'll mock it out.  When it's simple enough to use the class instead of a mock, I haven't noticed much extra fragility, which has answered my worries.

Lastly, I get the argument that they're no longer 'unit' tests, yet that's also prone to counterproductive hair-splitting.  A single method on a class is also a 'unit', so shouldn't we mock out any other methods it calls?  Almost never, in my experience.  Unit testing in my eyes should be pragmatic *first*, and theoretical purity, at best, a lagging second or third.

Answer (score 1):

For me the beauty of outside in TDD is that you end up with tests which are focussed on the desired *behaviour* and not on the implementation details.

If you want to refactor your class into several classes then I would not create separate tests for those new classes as the changes are an implementation detail (especially if the extracted classes are internal), the same as if you refactored to separate methods in the same class. This refactoring should not change the behaviour and so the changes should not need to change.

This changes when the classes are going to be reused. In this case they might move to a new package and so would need tests to move with them, or they might become public and directly exposed from the current package, in which case they might need a wider suite of more comprehensive tests (especially non happy path tests).

If you proceed along the path of writing tests 1-1 for the classes then all you will end up with is a lot of very brittle tests which need to be changed everytime you want to refactor your code, whcih becomes demotivating very quickly IMHO.